# How to match against the pattern of a partial function's case definition in a Scala macro?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10, scala-macros

As part of a macro, I want to manipulate the case definitions of a partial function.

To do so, I use a [Transformer](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Trees%24Transformer) to manipulate the case definitions of the partial function and a [Traverser](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Trees%24Traverser) to inspect the patterns of the case definitions:

```
def myMatchImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag, B: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)
    (expr: c.Expr[A])(patterns: c.Expr[PartialFunction[A, B]]): c.Expr[B] = {
  import c.universe._

  val transformer = new Transformer {
    override def transformCaseDefs(trees: List[CaseDef]) = trees map {
      case caseDef @ CaseDef(pattern, guard , body) => {
        // println(show(pattern))
        val traverser = new Traverser {
          override def traverse(tree: Tree) = tree match {
            // match against a specific pattern
          }
        }
        traverser.traverse(pattern)
      }
    }
  }

  val transformedPartialFunction = transformer.transform(patterns.tree)

  c.Expr[B](q"$transformedPartialFunction($expr)")
}
```

Now let us assume, the interesting data I want to match against is represented by the class Data (which is part of the object Example):

```
case class Data(x: Int, y: String)
```

When now invoking the macro on the example below

```
abstract class Foo
case class Bar(data: Data) extends Foo
case class Baz(string: String, data: Data) extends Foo

def test(foo: Foo) = myMatch(foo){
  case Bar(Data(x,y))    => y
  case Baz(_, Data(x,y)) => y
}
```

the patterns of the case definitions of the partial function are transformed by the compiler as following (the Foo, Bar, and Baz classes are members of the object Example, too):

```
(data: Example.Data)Example.Bar((x: Int, y: String)Example.Data((x @ _), (y @ _)))
(string: String, data: Example.Data)Example.Baz(_, (x: Int, y: String)Example.Data((x @ _), (y @ _)))
```

This is the result of printing the patterns as hinted in the macro above (using show), the raw abstract syntax trees (printed using showRaw) look like this:

```
Apply(TypeTree().setOriginal(Select(This(newTypeName("Example")), Example.Bar)), List(Apply(TypeTree().setOriginal(Select(This(newTypeName("Example")), Example.Data)), List(Bind(newTermName("x"), Ident(nme.WILDCARD)), Bind(newTermName("y"), Ident(nme.WILDCARD))))))

Apply(TypeTree().setOriginal(Select(This(newTypeName("Example")), Example.Baz)), List(Ident(nme.WILDCARD), Apply(TypeTree().setOriginal(Select(This(newTypeName("Example")), Example.Data)), List(Bind(newTermName("x"), Ident(nme.WILDCARD)), Bind(newTermName("y"), Ident(nme.WILDCARD))))))
```

How do I write a pattern-quote which matches against these trees?

Comment: Try printing the trees with `showRaw`, it will show you the exact structure of the tree (not just code-like representation).

Comment: @ghik I added the output of `shawRaw` to the question. Unfortunately, this doesn't help much either, since I don't know how to write a pattern for such a tree. I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is a special flavor of quasiquotes specifically for CaseDefs called `cq`:

```
override def transformCaseDefs(trees: List[CaseDef]) = trees map {
  case caseDef @ cq"$pattern if $guard => $body" => ...
}
```

Secondly, you should use `pq` to deconstruct patterns:

```
pattern match {
   case pq"$name @ $nested" => ...
   case pq"$extractor($arg1, $arg2: _*)" => ...
   ...
}
```

If you are interested in internals of trees that are used for pattern matching they are created by `patvarTransformer` defined in `TreeBuilder.scala`

On the other hand if you're are working with `UnApply` trees (that are being produced after typechecking) I have bad news for you: quasiquotes currently don't support them. Follow [SI-7789](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7789) to get notified when this is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for this hints on the quasiquotes. I managed to construct the desired pattern "by hand" and put the solution in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

After Den Shabalin pointed out, that quasiquotes can't be used in this particular setting, I managed to find a pattern which matches against the patterns of a partial function's case definitions.

The key problem is, that the constructor we want to match against (in our example `Data`) is stored in the `TypeTree` of the `Apply` node. Matching against a tree wrapped up in a `TypeTree` is a bit tricky, since the only extractor of this class (`TypeTree()`) isn't very helpful for this particular task. Instead we have to select the wrapped up tree using the `original` method:

```
override def transform(tree: Tree) = tree match {
  case Apply(constructor @ TypeTree(), args) => constructor.original match {
    case Select(_, sym) if (sym == newTermName("Data")) => ...
  }
}
```

In our use case the wrapped up tree is a `Select` node and we can now check if the symbol of this node is the one we are looking for.